# Translate encoding code from VB to Java

Tags: java, hash, encoding, vb6, sha256

I need to translate old code written in VisualBasic to Java.
VB code:

```
Dim mySHA256 As Object
Dim asc As Object
Dim TextToHash() As Byte
Dim mybytes() As Byte
Dim objXML As Object
Dim objNode As Object
Dim strResult As String

Set asc = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
Set mySHA256 = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed")

TextToHash = asc.GetBytes_4(sTextToHash)
mybytes = mySHA256.ComputeHash_2(TextToHash)

Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")

objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
objNode.nodeTypedValue = arrData
strResult = objNode.Text
```

It look completely magical to me. I need to have the same hash (strResult) in Java. My Java looks like this:

```
 byte[] bytes = text.getBytes( "UTF-8" );
 MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance( "SHA-256" );
 byte[] hash = messageDigest.digest( bytes );

 StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
 for( int i = 0; i < hash.length; i++ )
 {
     String hex = Integer.toHexString( 0xff & hash[ i ] );
     if( hex.length() == 1 )
     {
         hexString.append( '0' );
     }
     hexString.append( hex );
 }
```

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Post/explain your Java code that didnt work

Comment: What was wrong with your java code ? as Reimeus said, post your java code so we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. Correct Java code should look like this:

```
byte[] bytes = text.getBytes( "UTF-8" );
MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance( "SHA-256" );
byte[] hash = messageDigest.digest( bytes );
String result = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hash);
```